# Eclipse 3.4 TextViewer

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-3.4, eclipse-pdt

I am creating a plugin for Eclipse 3.4.  I created a plug-in development project using the application with a view.  Now I am trying to create a `TextViewer` the documentation says that it is located in `org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewer`.  But, this whole package is missing and eclipse cannot locate `TextViewer` class to import.  I want to know why is this package/class missing?  Also if it is really gone what took `TextViewer`'s place?

Answer (score 5):

```
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.jface.text
```

Add *org.eclipse.jface.text* as a dependency in your plugin manifest. You can use 3rd party tools (like IBM's [JAR Class Finder](https://www.alphaworks.ibm.com/tech/jarclassfinder/requirements)) to locate dependencies, or, alternatively, create a dummy plugin that imports everything from the target platform and use the Open Type dialog (CTRL+SHIFT+T).

If you don't like the manual route, have a look at the **Automated Management of Dependencies** feature in the manifest editor, though care should be taken with this.

Answer (score 1):

in 3.4 i have it inside

eclipse-jee-ganymede-win32\plugins\org.eclipse.jface.text_3.4.0.v20080603-2000.jar